# passing a div value inside a repeater to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i'm having trouble passing the contents of a div tag within an asp.net repeater control to a javascript function.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPickingSlips" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<div id="externalbox" style="width:5in">
    <div id="inputdata" ><%#Container.DataItem("PONumber")%></div>
</div>
<br />
PO Number: <asp:Label ID="lblPONumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem("PONumber")%>' /><br />
<hr />
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
  function get_object(id) {
   var object = null;
   if (document.layers) {
    object = document.layers[id];
   } else if (document.all) {
    object = document.all[id];
   } else if (document.getElementById) {
    object = document.getElementById(id);
   }
   return object;
  }

get_object("inputdata").innerHTML=DrawCode39Barcode(get_object("inputdata").innerHTML,1);
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Error Message: runtime error drawcode39barcode is undefined

What is rendered to the page is as follows:
    
        X6201302120845
    
    
    PO Number: X6201302120845

---

I have this working just fine with basic html - just not sure how to get js to pick up the value.

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique. But it the initial problem sounds like you are missing a script reference on the page. Is your barcode script included?

Comment: yes - i had the wrong path to the script file and it now throws a new error from within the script file:

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference in code39.js

    function filterInput(data) {
        var Result = "";
        var datalength = data.length;  //** errors here

Comment: if i run this with static html and js it works great - just bombing with the repeater

Comment: how would I get the divs to have different ids and pass those?

Comment: i modified code a bit by placing the function get_object above the repeater, commenting out the call to get_object and placed the call to get_object inside the item template. now i get the first bar code rendered but it won't do so for all remaining data elements in the repeater.

Comment: okay so i figured out how to make the div id unique by adding a guid as such:  <div id="a+<%=Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>"><%#Container.DataItem("PONumber")%></div>   but how do i pass this to javascript?  <div id="a+<%=Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>"><%#Container.DataItem("PONumber")%></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //get_object("inputdata").innerHTML = DrawCode39Barcode(get_object("?? how to pass the new id??").innerHTML, 1);
    </script>

Comment: oh i used this as a model to get a barcode: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146336/Creating-a-Code-Barcode-using-HTML-CSS-and-Java